# How to capture all Network traffics(http\https) of a Web Application using Java in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, network-programming

I want to record a Web Application traffic using Java code in the back-end and replay it after recording.

Is there any way to record Web Application traffic like we do in Load-runner using Java code?

Comment: If you look at the LoadRunner help files and online documentation you will find that utilities exist to convert the language from the Default 'C' language to the Java variation for the same virtual user.

Comment: Here is a link to help, http://commonlrissues.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-convert-c-web-vuser-script-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't automate everything or is not specific to Java, you can use Wireshark to retrieve HTTP/HTTPS requests and export them ( https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html ). Some other tools such as `PlayCap` allow to directly playback the wireshark capture.
Or you can write some Java code that mimics the requests and even load the wireshark capture file to send logged requests with any HTTP-able library.

You can also use directly `pcap` to retrieve packages (or the `jpcap` variant, written in Java, that may have some reusable code for your use-case), and try the similar approach to playback the capture.